# String increases in size when assigning the string an area within a char array

Tags: java

I've been having trouble figuring out as to why the `String stringMatch` is increasing in size. Since it increases in size, it goes out of bounds. I've been doing linear search through a text file and finding a word that matches what the user inputted. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this code?

```
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Please enter a word to be searched or type EINPUT to quit: ");
    String userString = input.next();
    while(!userString.equals("EINPUT")) {
        boolean bool = false;
        if(userString.equals("EINPUT")) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        char[] charSearch = userString.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < (text[i].length - charSearch.length); k++) {
                String stringMatch = new String(text[i], k, k + charSearch.length);
                if(stringMatch.equals(userString)) {
                    System.out.printf("Line number %d", i + 1);
                    bool = true;
                }
            }
        
        }
        if (bool == false) {
            System.out.printf("The word %s is not in the text file", userString);
        }
        System.out.print("Please enter a word to be searched or type EINPUT to quit: ");
        userString = input.next();
    }
```

The text document I am testing is a short one. It is as follows:

> It was a beautiful sunny day
>
> in the land of make believe

and this is the output

```
It w
t was
 was a
was a b
as a bea
s a beaut
 a beautif
a beautiful
 beautiful s
beautiful sun
eautiful sunny
autiful sunny d
utiful sunny day
```

After it reaches the end of the first line, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String stringMatch = new String(text[i], k, k + charSearch.length);
```

This line is the problem. The 3rd argument should be the **length of the new string, not the end index**. So you need to change from `k + charSearch.length` to `charSearch.length`, then it should work.

Comment: That makes so much sense! Thank you!

Comment: @Edge123 Good to hear! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.